# WPF button with graphics for both the button's background and content

Tags: c#, wpf, drawingbrush

I am skinning my app and want have a generic button graphic for all buttons, and then each button have unique content. I've created a DrawingBrush for the generic button graphic and applied it the button's background using a style defined in my resource dictionary. This all works great. However, when I then try to add something other than text to the Content of the button, no content shows up. I just get the background graphic. What do I need to do to have graphical content for both the button's background and content?

Comment: Need to see some XAML to help out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If templating, you need to have a `ContentPresenter` for displaying the content of the button.

[See here for an example on templating a button.](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html) In Stage 2, he adds a ContentPresenter to the template. (He actually adds two for a double-effect, but you could just use the simpler one.)

Comment: Thanks! I got it working. I forgot that in my buttons template I was using a Textblock and not a contentpresenter so that I could have text wrapping.